# Why aren't my JOptionPane messages working?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, joptionpane

I am writing a message dialog within an if statement. When I finish the message there are no errors. When I add an error message or any other message an error says "no suitable method" and "not applicable".

The code looks like this:

`OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong! Try again", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because there is no suitable method. You need to specify title and message of the dialog. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-)

For example:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong! Try again", "Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```